# Adjusting the nav width?

Tags: html, css

I am following the tutorial on w3c school for CSS, The navagation automatically goes full width without letting me adjust it. I want to use these same codes (cus i understand them)
How do i adjust width?

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ul` defaults to `display:block`. This defaults to `width: 100%`.

To override this, just put in any CSS width (this will override the default CSS). You can put in any valid [CSS length value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Or, to make it not full width by default (but just the necessary length), add `display: inline-block` to the `ul`.

Comment: Not only i got answers but some knowledge! superb <3

Comment: @BlueHorse I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

Add `width: n;`

to your ul selector in the CSS

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z91evcz0/)

**EDIT**

n in the code will be a number, followed by unit.  So, if you want it to be 550 pixels wide, n = 550px - as shown in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The default width is being 100% so overriding it by giving value like width:700px or width:80% will change the width to 700px or 80%

```
 ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        width: 700px;
    }
```